# Scaling function

Tags: wavelets, reference-request

Why is it important for the scaling function to have unit area in wavelets?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a normalization that makes some formulas simpler. An alternative would be to require that the $L^2$-norm (or some other norm) be $1$.